# How to remove the attributes from a function type?

Tags: templates, attributes, d

In the following sample the first test fails because of the function type attributes. The second test overrides the problem but it's too syntactically heavy.

```
import std.traits;

bool test1(T)()
{
    // clean but does not work !
    alias Fun = bool function(dchar);
    return (is(Unqual!T == Fun));    
}

bool test2(T)()
{
    // super heavy !
    return (isSomeFunction!T &&  is(ReturnType!T == bool) &&
        Parameters!T.length == 1 && is(Parameters!T[0] == dchar)
    );
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    import std.ascii: isAlpha;
    assert(test1!(typeof(&isAlpha)));
    assert(test2!(typeof(&isAlpha)));       
}
```

Is there a way to remove the attributes, just like Unqual does to storage classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#SetFunctionAttributes

std.traits.SetFunctionAttributes

```
 alias ExternC(T) = SetFunctionAttributes!(T, "C", functionAttributes!T);

 auto assumePure(T)(T t)
     if (isFunctionPointer!T || isDelegate!T)
 {
     enum attrs = functionAttributes!T | FunctionAttribute.pure_;
     return cast(SetFunctionAttributes!(T, functionLinkage!T, attrs)) t;
 }
```

That example adds the attribute `pure` but a similar pattern can remove attributes too.

Comment: Thx, this did the job (`SetFunctionAttributes!(T,"D",0)`)